# conditional IIF in a JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the next data base:

[image: Relation]

Table Bill:

[image: Table Bill]

Table Bill_Details:

[image: Table Bill_Details]

And Table Type:

[image: Table Type]

I want a query to show this result:

[image: Need]

The query as far goes like this:

```
SELECT 

Bill.Id_Bill, 
Type.Id_Type, 
Type.Info, 
Bill_Details.Deb, 
Bill_Details.Cre, 
Bill.NIT, 
Bill.Date2, 
Bill.Comt

FROM Type 

RIGHT JOIN (Bill INNER JOIN Bill_Details 
ON Bill.Id_Bill = Bill_Details.Id_Bill)
ON Type.Id_Type = Bill_Details.Id_Type

ORDER BY Bill.Id_Bill, Type.Id_Type;
```

With this result:

[image: Query3]

I'm not sure how to deal or how to include this:

```
Type.600, 
Type."TOTAL",
IIF(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre) >= 0, ABS(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre)), "" ), 
IIF(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre) <= 0, ABS(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre)), "" )
```

The previous code is the responsable of include new data in some fields, since all of the other fields will carry the same data of the upper register. I'll apreciate some sugestions to acomplish this.

Comment: After looking through all the detail shared, the actual problem is not described sufficiently.  Sometimes extra detail is okay, but really you just need to post the problem (last) query along with a precise description of the error or problem.  Tell us **what is being prompted for input... for which data fields is Access prompting**.  It's possible that there is just a typo in some field which Access doesn't recognize.  More generally, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do both of the queries in the union work separately?

Comment: The second query has a reference to `Type.Info`, but there is no reference to that table in the FROM clause.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I'll be making this shorter then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a revised version of the UNION which you removed from the question.  The original query was a good start, but you just did not provide sufficient details about the error or problem you were experiencing.  My comments were not meant to have you remove the problem query, only that you needed to provide more details about the error or problem.  In the future if you have a UNION, make sure the each query of the UNION works separately.  Then you could debug problems easier, one step at a time.

Problems which I corrected in the second query of the UNION:

- Removed reference to table [Type] in the query, since it was not part of the FROM clause.  Instead, I replaced it with a literal value.
- Fixed FROM clause to join both [Bill] and [Bill_Details] tables.  You had fields from both tables, so why would you not join on them just like in the first query of the UNION?
- Grouped on all fields from table [Bill] referenced in the SELECT clause.  You must either group on all fields, or include them in aggregate expressions like Sum() or First(), etc.
- Replaced empty strings with Nulls for the False cases on Iif() statements.

---

```
SELECT 
    Bill.Id_Bill, Type.Id_Type, Type.Info,
    Bill_Details.Deb, 
    Bill_Details.Cre, 
    Bill.NIT, Bill.Date2, Bill.Comt
FROM 
    Type RIGHT JOIN (Bill INNER JOIN Bill_Details
        ON Bill.Id_Bill = Bill_Details.Id_Bill)
    ON Type.Id_Type = Bill_Details.Id_Type;

UNION

SELECT 
    Bill.Id_Bill, 600 As Id_Type, "TOTAL" As Info,
    IIF(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre) >= 0, ABS(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre)), Null ) As Deb, 
    IIF(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre) <= 0, ABS(SUM(Bill_Details.Deb) - Sum(Bill_Details.Cre)), Null ) As Cre,
    Bill.NIT, Bill.Date2, Bill.Comt

FROM Bill INNER JOIN Bill_Details
    ON Bill.Id_Bill = Bill_Details.Id_Bill

GROUP BY Bill.Id_Bill, Bill.NIT, Bill.Date2, Bill.Comt;
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much! it is very well explained! I'll be checking this query in detail, so useful

Comment: Please, can you tell what to edit or how to show this question useful in order to have positive or zero votes, I don't want to edit and have a worse reception

Comment: Now that the question has been viewed and answered, it probably will not get many upvotes even if you improve it because it deals with basic concepts of unions and aggregate queries.  I hope it is useful to you, but others view this as a basic tutorial type of question that could be answered by studying Access SQL in other ways.  They may not view it as a very critical question which is useful to many users, but instead they probably view it as a specialized question just for your situation.  These types rarely get many upvotes.

Comment: Your question has many positive aspects like a clear explanation of the data, and example data, and expected output, and an example of code that you attempted -- these are all good things.  But it was also long compared to other questions.  Too many images of data can turn users away.

Comment: The original question also had incomplete description of the errors and the description of the SQL was a little confusing.  That is probably why you got initial downvotes.  But even after editing, it was not clear what you needed.  Since I read both your original and the edited, I was able to understand you better, but other users probably were still confused after the edit.

Comment: Your actual question was **"How can I add summary rows inline with my other data rows?  I think that I need an SQL UNION, but I cannot figure out how to properly sum the values for each bill and include the sum on its own line."**, but you were not able to express that very concisely.  The main question was lost in all of the other details and I think others are not patient enough to read it all.  Sorry that I cannot offer more help, but I hope my perspective helps you understand what small things you could improve next time.

Comment: I appreciate all your comments!